# How can I see all formulae available in a specific tap using Brew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-management

Suppose I have added a new tap to Brew using `brew tap ...`.

I've tried looking into `brew search`, `brew tap`, and `brew tap-info`, but none of these subcommand present any suitable options.

How can I list all formulae available within that tap?

Comment: @nohillside - I've updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334787/homebrew-get-list-of-formulas-in-a-tap) Stack Overflow article:

> List of formulae in a tap can be found by running `brew tap-info $TAP --json`
>
> To turn this into a proper readable format we can run `brew tap-info $TAP --json | jq -r '.[]|(.cask_tokens[])'`
>
> **Example**: To find all formulae in homebrew/cask-fonts we can do: `brew tap-info homebrew/cask-fonts --json | jq -r '.[]|(.cask_tokens[])'`

#### Break down of the command:

1. `brew tap-info homebrew/cask-fonts --json` lists JSON info of the taps and some other stuff ([output](https://pastebin.com/HTJUVnvE))
2. `jq -r '.[]` removes the outside square bracket ([output](https://pastebin.com/0NC6aJ6E))
3. `|(.cask_tokens[])'` gets the JSON value of the key `cask_tokens`

**TL;DR**: Running `brew tap-info <tap-here> --json | jq -r '.[]|(.cask_tokens[])'` will give you the formulae from that tap.

**Note** If this fails to list all try running `brew tap-info <tap-here> --json | jq -r '.[]|(.formula_names[],.cask_tokens[])'`

Comment: Why is `.formula_names[]` necessary? May a tap contain both formulae and casks?

Comment: @Shuzheng Hmm thats interesting. For me this change of removing `.formula_names[]` made no difference to the output. From [this](https://pastebin.com/0NC6aJ6E) paste we can see that there is a field with the key `"formula_names"`. I am not sure if it is required to run with `.formula_names[]`, but since the field is there in the JSON output I'm leaving it there for now.